# Commit failed - exit code 128 received

Tags: github, cmd, git-commit

I was trying to commit to Github desktop(windows 8.1)(my first time I only did it on Linux before), and I got this error `Commit failed - exit code 128 received`, and this section

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

which apparently I should run in the prompt.The thing is I don't know which path I should set in the prompt before running these commands and I couldn't find `git.exe` I found `git.bat` are they the same?

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin\git.bat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those config options will be globally set once you have run them. However, I never had to set them as GitHub Desktop automatically did that for me. Go through the settings in GitHub and make sure you have defined your details correctly.

If you need to run them manually, GIT.EXE will be found in the GitHub program files folder.

`cd \<path to git.exe>
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"`

It does sound like your setup hasn't been completed 100%.